# Display time with offset

Tags: javascript

I need to display a time of an even with JS in the following format: **10:30 am**

The value I have to work with comes in the following format:

```
2016-01-31 15:13:33
```

I also need to account for time offset, which I get in the following format: **-360**, which is -6 hrs.

I use jQuery for my project and have a function that I use, where I convert military time to standard:

```
function convHour( hr, mn ) {
    return (hr == 24 ? 'midnight' : (hr > 12 ? hr - 12 : hr) + ':' + (mn == 30 ? mn : '00') + (hr >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am'));
}
```

So, I'm trying to pull it all together. What am I missing?

```js
var mytime = '2016-01-31 15:13:33',
  offset = '-360',
  nutime = new Date(mytime + offset * 60),
  hr = nutime.getHours(),
  mn = nutime.getMinutes();

function convHour(hr, mn) {
  return (hr == 24 ? 'midnight' : (hr > 12 ? hr - 12 : hr) + ':' + (mn == 30 ? mn : '00') + (hr >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am'));
}

alert(hr + ' ' + mn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mytime = '2016-01-31 15:13:33',
  offset = '-360',
  nutime = new Date(mytime + offset * 60),
```

You're trying to construct a Date with a formated date string plus an offset in seconds, it's not consistent - you can only add seconds to seconds.

Something like that should work:

```
  var mytime = '2016-01-31 15:13:33',
  offset = -360;

  var nutime = new Date();
  mytime = mytime.replace(' ', 'T' );
  nutime.setTime(new Date( mytime ).getTime() + offset * 60 * 1000);
```

Alternatively:

```
  var mytime = '2016-01-31 15:13:33',
  offset = '+06:00';

  var nutime = new Date();
  mytime = mytime.replace(' ', 'T' );  
  nutime = new Date( mytime + offset );
```

Note that `15:13:33` is local time, `15:13:33Z` is GMT, `15:13:33+06:00` is GMT-6

Comment: Several things (actually my sample code was incorrect). See https://jsfiddle.net/08mkdg9y/1/

Comment: Hmm, I see you jsfiddle and it works, however the mytime has a letter T in the string --  as soon as I remove it script breaks... The sting that I work with looks like this '2016-02-01 18:48:28', with no "T" separating the date and time.

Comment: It should work without a T too (I've just tested with '2016-02-01 18:48:28').

Comment: I agree it should, but I get the same results on my page as in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/08mkdg9y/2/ --  NaN NaN

Comment: What's wrong ? The alert looks right to me (15:13 minus 6 => 9:13).

Comment: Wow, this is weird. When I test in Firefox I get 'Nan Nan', but when I tested in Chrome it gives: '9 13'. IE and Safari also choked.

Comment: Confirmed. The format '2016-02-01 18:48:28' is probably not quite legal. You can fix it by replacing space by `T`, even if it's not pretty it will work.

Comment: See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15.

And for +6h from UTC timezone (not from local), see https://jsfiddle.net/08mkdg9y/4/

Comment: Right on! I've added replace(' ', 'T') and it works like a charm. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer with an alternative (BTW I don't know if you're calculating from local or GMT).

Comment: It looks like mine is local.Thanks again.